# How to grep/sed/awk/print lines contain two word or maximum words in it

Tags: awk, sed

Any way to view(/grep/awk/sed/print/printf) lines which have maximum words minimum range X and maximum Y (X and y number 1-10..) Example:

**download kali linux virtualbox**
2
3.5%
10:53
102.2%
0.4
24.3%
**how to install kali linux in vmware**
2
3.5%
0:37
5.8%
0.0
1.4%
**install kali linux on virtualbox**
2
3.5%
0:32
5.0%
0.0
1.2%
**kali linux**
2
3.5%
0:08
1.4%
0.0
0.3%
**kali linux install virtualbox**
I need to print text words but minimum and maximum words need to be there.
 
Output need to be
cat atom.txt
download kali linux VirtualBox
how to install kali linux in vmware
install kali linux on virtualbox
kali linux
kali linux install virtualbox

Comment: I tried this sort -rn demo.txt |uniq -w1 but it is printing 1-word lines as well.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: give an input sample and the expected output

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this question is about or what those blocks of text in it are intended to represent. Please read [ask] and [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting] for how to format the sample input, output, and code in your questions. Look at some other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy in `awk`.

`NF` is a variable injected for every matched pattern that contains the number of wors in the line.

`$0` contains the line itself.

To apply a transformation to every line you simply don't specify any pattern.

So to `print $0` only if `NF > 1 && NF < 10`, the code is:

```
awk '{ if (NF > 1 && NF < 10) print $0 }' atom.txt
```

Change `1` and `10` based on your needs.

The output:

```
download kali linux virtualbox
how to install kali linux in vmware
install kali linux on virtualbox
kali linux
kali linux install virtualbox
```

#### EDIT

Out of curiosity I checked if you can express this even more concisely by making the `if` condition part of the pattern you want to match and it works, so you can also say:

```
awk 'NF > 1 && NF < 10 { print $0 }' atom.txt
```

Where again you are free to change the range based on your needs.

For example if you change `10` to `3`:

```
awk 'NF > 1 && NF < 3 { print $0 }' atom.txt
```

The output becomes:

```
kali linux
```

Comment: default behavior for a true condition is to print the current line so, `awk 'NF > 1 && NF < 10' atom.txt` will also work

Comment: The example I've shared above is the list of keywords and some useless texts. I got some more files that contain the single-word keywords. The script you shared above is skipping them. For example, if you put Kali in place of Kali Linux. Kali is getting ignored. How to add words which contain more than 3 characters / or add some more words on basis of the number of minimum x and maximum y characters in it?